# How to resolve nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/SessionDataStore?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty, wiremock

I am migrating an old multi-module project. I cannot migrate as it has many dependencies, so I am making a single migration, hoping it will be easier.

I upgraded Spring-boot to version 2.4.3 and constantly getting these errors:

> Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
> Unable to start web server; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'JettyServletWebServerFactory' defined in
> class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory]:
> Factory method 'JettyServletWebServerFactory' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/SessionDataStore     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)

My version of the jetty is 9.2.28.v20190418.

I am breaking my head trying to resolve this issue but made no progress.

How can I resolve it?

**UPDATE:**

I tried downgrading Spring Boot to 2.3.3.RELEASE, I tried upgrading all jetty components to 11.0.1, no difference. It gets to less clear, more marginal error messages.

**UPDATE 2:**

When I start the Spring boot app itself, I got a message:

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.configureSession(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:242)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'void org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.setMaxInactiveInterval(int)'
```

The method's class, org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/Users/dmytro/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.2.28.v20190418/jetty-server-9.2.28.v20190418.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/SessionHandler.class
```

I still cannot understand how to solve it as I didn't work with `Jetty` too much before, but it looks like something.

**UPDATE 3:**

After endless hours of debugging, I figured out that the conflict arises between `wiremock:2.27.2` and `spring-boot:2.4.3`. They both depend on incompatible versions of `jetty`, `jetty:9.2.28.v20190418` and `jetty:9.4.38.v20210224`.

The issue is that I cannot remove the wiremock. I cannot downgrade Spring Boot, as wiremock is lagging. Whats other alternatives do I have?

**UPDATE 4:**
I posted an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/6065). I hope there is no need to patch the wiremock or rewrite the test codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Jetty Github issue, I got an answer that resolved my issue to use `jetty-bom`, so `jetty` can take care of itself:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

It worked seamlessly for me.

**UPDATE:**

It worked seamlessly until I did `mvn clean install`, so another dependency that absolutely necessary in my case:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
  <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
  <version>2.27.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the problem is already solved. But worth mentioning maybe help other in future if they have same problem.
I had the same error but in my case there was another dependency which bring jetty server in addition to spring-boot.
With

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

I figure out two different version of Jetty was pulled to my project. I just exclude Jetty server from external dependency in maven and every thing worked fine.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-jetty9</artifactId>
            <version>${metrics.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.4.3 is based on Jetty 9.4.38.v20210224. The class `SessionDataStore` reported in the `NoClassDefFoundException` isn't present in the Jetty version, which you are using.

So, the solution will be probably to upgrade to Jetty 9.4.38.v20210224.

Comment: Do I need to exclude a specific jetty library? They have a set of things such as servlets, core, server, client, and more.

Comment: I think, that you should either import dependency management from the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.4.3` or try to use same versions as defined there in your project. So, I don't think, that you have to exclude something.

Comment: I made an update of my post. It looks like it all gets messed up because of Wiremock and incompatible jetty versions. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by upgrading *com.github.tomakehurst* from 2.27.2 to 2.34.0 like shown below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
        <version>2.34.0</version>
        <scope>test,compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```